# object of SQLiteOpenHelper only can be declared in onAttach and null elsewhere

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

i have a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, in the activity, i declared the variables `MQTT_Settings_DB` and `SQLiteDatabase` as shown beow in the code.

the problem is when i declared the variable `MQTT_Settings_DB` and initialised globally as show shown in the code, at run time, this line

```
this.sqliteDB = this.mqttSettingsDB.getWritableDatabase();
```

that exists in `commitToSQLiteDB()` causes the App to crash and i receive `NPE`, to solve this issue, i placed the declaration of the

```
this.mqttSettingsDB
```

in `onAttach()` as follows

```
onAttach() {

this.mqttSettingsDB = new MQTT_Settings_DB(getActivity());
}
```

the App does not crash.

why the object `MQTT_Settings_DB` is defined in `onAttach` and can not be defined globally?

**code**:

```
private MQTT_Settings_DB mqttSettingsDB = new MQTT_Settings_DB(getActivity());
private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = null;
....
....
....
protected boolean commitToSQLiteDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (this.mqttSettingsDB == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "@commitToSQLiteDB(): this.mqttSettingsDB == null");
        this.mqttSettingsDB = new MQTT_Settings_DB(getActivity());
    }
    if (this.sqliteDB == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "@commitToSQLiteDB(): this.sqliteDB == null");
        this.sqliteDB = this.mqttSettingsDB.getWritableDatabase();// always causes error??
    } else {

        if (!this.sqliteDB.isOpen()) {
            this.sqliteDB = this.mqttSettingsDB.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Context` available only in Fragment life cycle methods

Comment: getActivity will return null if you call it before `onAttach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private MQTT_Settings_DB mqttSettingsDB = new MQTT_Settings_DB(getActivity());
```

`getActivity()` returns `null` before the fragment is attached to an activity. Passing null to a `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor doesn't crash immediately but it will when you try to actually open the database with e.g. `getWritableDatabase()`.